# Deallocate NSOperationQueue as soon as all operations in queue are finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I want to deallocate NSOperationQueue when all the operations in progress are finished executing.
So far, I have coded below but as far as I know `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` is async call and could not hold from my operationQueue getting nil.

```
- (void)deallocOperationQueue
{
    [operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
    operationQueue = nil;
}
```

Comment: Why would you think a method with `wait` in its name is async?

Comment: You are thinking of the problem the wrong way.  The queue will be dealloc'd when there are no strong references to it.  You should set the reference to `nil` when you no longer need the reference, not when you no longer need the queue.

Comment: I am using controller class which remains alive throughout project. I cant set it to nil from dealloc etc.

Comment: so waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished is not async?

Comment: You don't need to wait for all operations to finish.  Just set `operationQueue` to nil when you're done with it.  If the queue still has operations, nothing happens to them; they will still complete.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation?  Of course a `wait` method is not async.  How would it be waiting if it were?

Comment: I agree with everyone else, I don't know why you would want to do this. If there is a good reason then you could KVO onto the queues operationCount property, then set it to nil when it changes to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Avi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5085011/avi)

> You don't need to wait for all operations to finish. Just set
>   operationQueue to nil when you're done with it. If the queue still has
>   operations, nothing happens to them; they will still complete.

```
- (void)deallocOperationQueue
{
    operationQueue = nil;
}
```

I have tested the code and confirm that stated behaviour does happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass an NSOperationQueue and observe the **operations** key path until it reaches zero:

```
class DownloadOperationQueue: NSOperationQueue {

    private static var operationsKeyPath: String {
        return "operations"
    }

    deinit {
        self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "operations")
    }

    var completionBlock: (() -> Void)? {
        didSet {
            self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: DownloadOperationQueue.operationsKeyPath, options: .New, context: nil)
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if let operationPath = keyPath where operationPath == DownloadOperationQueue.operationsKeyPath {
            if self.operations.count == 0 {
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ 
                    self.completionBlock?()
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When completed:

```
var operationQueue: DownloadOperationQueue? = DownloadOperationQueue()

// Add your operations ...

operationQueue?.completionBlock = {
    operationQueue = nil
}
```